# Java generic collection, cannot add list to list

Tags: java, generics, collections

Why does the following

```
public class ListBox {
    private Random random = new Random();
    private List<? extends Collection<Object>> box;

public ListBox() {
    box = new ArrayList<>();
}

public void addTwoForks() {
    int sizeOne = random.nextInt(1000);
    int sizeTwo = random.nextInt(1000);

    ArrayList<Object> one = new ArrayList<>(sizeOne);
    ArrayList<Object> two = new ArrayList<>(sizeTwo);

    box.add(one);
    box.add(two);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new ListBox().addTwoForks();
}
}
```

Not work? Just toying around with generics for the purpose of learning and I expected that I would be able to insert anything that extends Collection in there but I get this error:

```
The method add(capture#2-of ? extends Collection<Object>) in the type List<capture#2-of ? extends Collection<Object>> is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList<Object>)
The method add(capture#3-of ? extends Collection<Object>) in the type List<capture#3-of ? extends Collection<Object>> is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList<Object>)

at ListBox.addTwoForks(ListBox.java:23)
at ListBox.main(ListBox.java:28)
```

Comment: This answer on SO might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You've declared `box` to be a `List` of something that extends `Collection` of `Object`.  But according to the Java compiler, it could be *anything* that extends `Collection`, i.e. `List<Vector<Object>>`.  So it must disallow `add` operations that take the generic type parameter for this reason.  It can't let you add an `ArrayList<Object>` to a `List` that could be `List<Vector<Object>>`.

Try removing the wildcard:

```
private List<Collection<Object>> box;
```

This should work because you can certainly add an `ArrayList<Object>` to a `List` of `Collection<Object>`.

Comment: This makes sense, but if I wanted to add a vector and an arraylist? Edit, link in first comment explains the use of super ;)

Comment: @arynaq both of those implement List, so you could do `List<List<Object>> box`. Then you can add both Vectors and ArrayLists, though you can only get them out as `List<Object>`. If you need specific methods on `ArrayList` or `Vector`, you'll have to test-and-downcast or come up with something else -- but first make sure you really need that!

Comment: Alternately, `List<Collection<Object>>` as suggested would already work for vectors and arraylists, as well as e.g. sets.