# Insert object into List wildcard extending interface

Tags: java, interface, insert, wildcard, extends

So I have an interface

```
public interface Identity {

abstract void setKey(String key);
abstract String getKey();
}
```

That I want to use for an insert sort function

```
public static void InsertIdentity(Identity identity, ArrayList<? extends Identity> list) {
    int i = 0;
    Identity id;
    while (i < list.size()) {
        if ((id = list.get(i)).getKey().compareTo(identity.getKey()) < 0) {
            i++;
        }else{break;}
    }
    list.add(i, identity);
}
```

But obviously I cannot add an Identity to a ArrayList - ? extends Identity

I was wondering if there is a way around this?

I know Java has other ways of doing this task but I would like this function to work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java generic collection, cannot add list to list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16305164/java-generic-collection-cannot-add-list-to-list). And there are many more questions dealing with this issue ...

Comment: I know why it doesn't work, I was hoping someone could help me find a way around it

Comment: The way around it is to not declare your parameter with an upper bounded wildcard.

Comment: But then it defeats the purpose of the function

Comment: You obviously want to make your method work on _various types_. This cries for a type parameter: `<T extends Identity> void insertIdentity(T identitiy, List<T> list) { ... }`. By the way: Keep on using Java's code conventions, and use interfaces where appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make the [method generic](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html):

```
public static <T extends Identity> void InsertIdentity(T identity, ArrayList<T> list) {
    //...
```

You may need to make other methods generic as well, if you use this approach.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was trying to do something like this earlier but couldn't get it to work. Now I know!

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest the following:

```
public static <I extends Identity> void InsertIdentity(I identity, ArrayList<I> list)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I was trying to do something like this earlier but couldn't get it to work. Now I know!

Answer (score 2):

This can work, depending on how you will use the InsertIdentity method:

```
public static <T extends Identity> void InsertIdentity(T identity, ArrayList<T> list) {
```